# Forge Viewer PDF extension allow Document Browser to stay docked to side

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I would like to keep the document browser docked to one side of the viewer with the thumbnails visible and no option to collapse the menu.

```
   export const initializePDF = async (url: string) => {
    const viewerDiv: any = document.getElementById("MyViewerDiv");
    const viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(viewerDiv);
    var options = {
        env: "Local",
        useADP: false,
    };
    Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, () => {
        viewer.start();
        if (!url) console.log("error loading PDF");
        viewer.loadExtension("Autodesk.PDF").then(() => {
            viewer.loadModel(url, { page: 3 });
            viewer.loadExtension("Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore");
            viewer.loadExtension("Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsGui");
            viewer.loadExtension("Autodesk.DocumentBrowser");
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that most of the properties and functions of the **Autodesk.DocumentBrowser** extension just make it easier to get to the various **DOM** objects of the panel, but then you can use their **DOM** functions and properties to achieve what you need. Here is the source code of the extension: https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/extensions/DocumentBrowser/DocumentBrowser.js

To move the panel to the **top-left** and show the **Thumbnails** tab you can do this:

```
let ext = await NOP_VIEWER.loadExtension("Autodesk.DocumentBrowser");
ext.ui.panel.container.style.left = 0;
ext.ui.panel.container.style.top = 0;
ext.ui.panel.panelTabs[1].click();
```

[image]